# osgi.extender; (osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.registrar) in Jenkins

Tags: eclipse, components, osgi

I'm trying to perform an Eclipse migration, and during that I'm updating the required components whichever is compatible with my product, and after adding the required dependencies during deployment the Jenkins build is facing the below issue:

```
{osgi.os=win32, osgi.ws=win32, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, osgi.arch=x86_64}    
Cannot resolve project dependencies:
    [ERROR]   Software being installed: ecl_purevariants raw:6.0.4.'SNAPSHOT'/format(n[.n=0;[.n=0;[-S]]]):6.0.4-SNAPSHOT
    [ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot 10.0.11 requires 'osgi.extender; (osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.registrar)' but it could not be found
    [ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: com.ps.consul.eclipse.purevariants.birt.feature.group 6.0.2.685 depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.birt.feature.group 2.1.2.v20070205-1728
    [ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: ecl_purevariants raw:6.0.4.'SNAPSHOT'/format(n[.n=0;[.n=0;[-S]]]):6.0.4-SNAPSHOT depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.ps.consul.eclipse.purevariants.birt.feature.group 0.0.0
```

If any of you faced such issues, your inputs would be helpful to resolve this issue. Thank you !

Comment: That capabilty seems to be provided by the `org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle` plug-in which is only in Eclipse 4.28  (2023-06) onwards

Comment: Could you please share a reference URL about this if you have ?

Comment: I don't have a URL, I'm looking at the Provide-Capability headers in the various Eclipse plug-ins